# How to dynamically get on url the id on view page in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

i have on controller views page code this button:

```
<button
<a href="<?= Backend::url('vimagem/pacientes/pacientes/pdf/1') ?>" 
class="btn btn-primary oc-icon-sign-out">export</a>
</button>
```

how i can get the id of this url ?

```
<button
<a href="<?= Backend::url('vimagem/pacientes/pacientes/pdf/:id') ?>" 
class="btn btn-primary oc-icon-sign-out">export</a>
</button>
```

This way is not working... any ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From backend we can get params but we need to use `index`. just use below code to get id.

> **$this->params[0]** - will get you first param value.

```php
<a href="<?= Backend::url('vimagem/pacientes/pacientes/pdf/' . $this->params[0]) ?>"
```

> Here index `0` denote that we want to use first param. `index count starts after [param]action name and its based on 0-index`. so first item has 0 index.

If your back-end controller is using `Form-Controller behavior` then use this answer both will work.

[October CMS | In the controller, create edit button on preview.htm which then links to update.htm with the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451425/october-cms-in-the-controller-create-edit-button-on-preview-htm-which-then-li)

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Hello Hardik Satasiya, i will test it, and i will leave comment. thank you!

Comment: Hello @HardikSatasiya, sorry for the big delay on saying you - Thank You - for your help, it worked! :) Stay safe!